# Java how to add null values to node

Tags: java, nodes

How can I add a node with a null value in java? Here is the following relevant code.

```
    int beadNum = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    Node necklace;
    st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
    String beads = st.nextToken();
    int max = 0;
    char[] beadArr = beads.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < beadNum; i++) {
        Node temp = new Node(beadArr[i]);
        temp.next = necklace;
        necklace = temp;
    }
```

My Node class is shown as well.

```
    class Node {
        Node next;
        char val;
        public Node(char val) {
            this.val = val;
        }
    }
```

I want 'necklace' to be null so I can add to 'necklace' without the first value to bother me.

Comment: in the 1st iteration necklace is null. Isn't it?

Comment: What class are you using a node in? What is the reference variable to the first node? Please paste your full code.

Comment: Besides, `Node()` accepts a `char` not a `char[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since necklace is not initialized (which will actually be a warning and I strongly think you should initialize it to `null`), It is already `null`. During the first iteration, you need not worry about it.